# How to parse a rdf format file from command line

Tags: bash, awk, rdf

I'd like to parse the `install.rdf` file inside the [uBlock0.firefox-legacy.xpi](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/releases/download/firefox-legacy-1.16.4.10/uBlock0.firefox-legacy.xpi) file.

I want to get the `em:id`, `em:name`, `em:version`, `em:description` and `em:homepageURL` from the `install.rdf` file like this :

```
em:id           uBlock0@raymondhill.net
em:name         uBlock Origin
em:version      1.16.4.10
em:description  Finally, an efficient blocker. Easy on CPU and memory.
em:homepageURL  https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock
```

EDIT 1: `xmllint` is not able to parse the `install.rdf` file :

```sh
$ cat install.rdf | xmllint --xpath '((//em:description)[1] | (//em:id)[1] | (//em:name)[1] | (//em:version)[1] | (//em:homepageURL)[1])/text()' -
XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
XPath evaluation failure
$ echo $?
10
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Is this review request?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I've just updated the title and the introduction phrase. Hoping, this is a little more clear

Comment: "looking for another tool" -- off-site resource requests are explicitly off-topic. See #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've just taken your remark into account and edited my question. Can you please undo your close vote ?

Comment: There is a Python lib for this: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I don't know how to use this python module, isn't there a way to do it like calling some tool from a bash script ?

Comment: @SebMa Not really, you need to write Python code.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I was hoping some tool like [pup](https://github.com/EricChiang/pup), but `pup` only handles html. So I can conclude there is no rdf command line parser yet, right ?

Comment: It's just XML as far as I know so maybe try xmllint https://danielmiessler.com/blog/extract-xml-elements-using-xmllint/?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `xmllint` says `XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix` upon this simple command : `xmllint --xpath '//em:description' install.rdf`

Answer (score 5):

It's an RDF/XML file. An RDF/XML parser can parse the file into an RDF graph, and then a SPARQL query can be used to extract the desired information. A simple SPARQL query would be:

```
SELECT * { <urn:mozilla:install-manifest> ?property ?value }
```

But that returns more properties than those listed in the question; the results can be limited like so:

```
PREFIX em: <http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#>
SELECT * {
    VALUES (?property) { (em:id) (em:name) (em:version) (em:description) (em:homepageURL) }
    <urn:mozilla:install-manifest> ?property ?value
}
```

We can store this query in a file `query.sparql` for later use.

### With Apache Jena

RDF/XML and SPARQL are W3C standards with a number of implementations. I tend to use [Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org), a Java-based RDF framework which comes with a `sparql` command line tool. With the simple query, it can be called like so:

```sh
sparql --data install.rdf "SELECT * { <urn:mozilla:install-manifest> ?property ?value }"
```

A number of output formats are supported (see `sparql --help`); TSV (tab-separated) is a good choice for further processing. With the query file saved earlier, it can be called like this:

```sh
sparql --data install.rdf --query query.sparql --results TSV --quiet
```

Output:

```
?property   ?value
<http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#id> "uBlock0@raymondhill.net"
<http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#name>   "uBlock Origin"
<http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#version>    "1.16.4.10"
<http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#description>    "Finally, an efficient blocker. Easy on CPU and memory."
<http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#homepageURL>    "https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock"
```

### With Rasqal

Another option is [Rasqal](http://librdf.org/rasqal/), part of the [Redland RDF Libraries](http://librdf.org). Rasqal doesn't require a JVM to run and can be installed via the usual package managers, but compared to Jena it's a bit buggy. It comes with a command line tool called `roqet`:

```sh
roqet -D install.rdf -r tsv query.sparql
```

The output is the same as for `sparql` above.

Comment: very helpful answers. I don't normally think of `rdf` as being a linux based "system". Are all these tools available on Linux (which distro do you use?). Thanks for any info.

Comment: All these options will work on Linux, Windows and macOS. Jena is Java-based so will run on any OS after a JVM has been installed. Redland has binaries available for download for the major OSes. Personally my main OS is macOS but I assumed that you are looking for Linux options based on the command line snippet in your edit. I don't have a particular preference or expertise when it comes to Linux distros; Debian and Ubuntu have served me well in the past.